# Error Animating in image slider jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do an image slider in jquery. I have written the below code. I am unable to understand how to animate the images instead of changing the src attribute.

> https://jsfiddle.net/2tsfnauk/2/

```
var tyInterval = setInterval(function() {

    $('#first').attr('src', $('#images li').eq(0).children().attr('src'))
    $('#head').html($('#images li').eq(0).children().attr('alt'))

    var iHtml = $('#images li').eq(0).remove();
    $('#images').append(iHtml);


}, 2000)
```

And in initial load of page an empty div is shown. what is the reason for it

Comment: use jquery cycle plugins, those are free and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

what if you tried the following code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var carousel= $('#carousel');
  var head= $('#head');

  // variable will be used to loop on all images
  var count = 1;
  // find all images inside the ul with id = images
  var max = $('#images img').length;
  // make sure that the ul is hidden
  $('#images').hide();
  var tyInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var html = $($('#images li').eq(count).html());
    carousel.append(html);
    head.text(html.attr('alt'))
    count = count +1;
    if(count==max) // when you reach the last image then reset the counter
        count=0;
  }, 2000)
  // to load for the first time
    var html = $('#images li').eq(0).html();
    carousel.append(html);
    head.text(html.attr('alt')
})
```

here an update on your [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2tsfnauk/4/)

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You should use `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`.

Like in this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#images li:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#images > :first-child').fadeOut().next('li').fadeIn().end().appendTo('#images');
        $('#head').html($('#images li').eq(0).children().attr('alt'));
    }, 3000);
});
```

Here's a fiddle I made https://jsfiddle.net/2tsfnauk/9/ with additional changes in the markup and CSS